# One server or two server for web application

Tags: java, eclipse, angular

I created a springboot application.I have a embedded web server. When I change some files in java, (I use eclipse) build process is run automatically. It is okey but when I change some files in javascript side, I only use Ctrl +S keywords to see my changes. In this situation, I use one server and everything is working. First question is that when I change some files in javascript, do I have to start java build process for all project with Eclipse?

I saw in a video, teacher uses 2 different web server for springboot project. One of them is for backend, the other one is for angular. (he uses ng-serve command to create angular server). My undersstanding is that when teacher change on some js files, He do not use Ctrl+S,changes can be seen on server immediately. Is it the only difference for this approach?In one server approach, I can see changes in front-end side just ctlr+s command. Second approach does not use this approach.

Can you help me about frond-end build process?

Comment: Perhaps the instructor has the IDE set to auto save when changes are made to the Angular code?

Comment: But why do he use two server?In one server, I can working for both frond-end and back-end.

Comment: You would have to ask the instructor that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is really an eclipse question, and has nothing to do with angular. Check the `Project Properties -> Deployment Assembly` section in your IDE, if it's mapping your project folders containing static files (JavaScript, CSS, HTML) to `/` or `/static` or appropriate path, you can just save the files and see changes deployed on the local server immediately.
2. The project is deployed after each build. You can setup the project to build automatically, there's a rather evident option in the menubar.
3. So: no servers, one server or two servers? Depends on what your frontend application is doing. If you're just saying hello world, you can do so without any server. If you're making the same hello world application available to other people on the network, you need one server. And if your application needs data from a backend in order to work, you *may* start a second server that provides API to the backend.